# Show that $2x^3+2x^2-10x+6$ is positive if $x>1$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Show that $2x^3+2x^2-10x+6$ is positive if $x>1$

I have tried to solve it using mean value theorem but it doesn't work. Please anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Maybe, you should  try to get an idea of what your function behaves like/such looks like, by studying the derivative. That might help.

Comment: The original question did not have the [tag:calculus] tag, the asker may not be able to use derivatives.

Comment: Of course, the asker *did* mention the Mean Value Theorem. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Let $f(x)=2x^3+2x^2-10x+6$. Trying to use the Mean Value Theorem, you computed the derivative $f'$. Note that $f(1)=f'(1)=0$ which implies that $1$ is a double root of $f$, that is the polynomial $f$ is divisible by $(x-1)^2$. Now you should be able to get the complete factorization of $f$ and to show the given inequality.

Answer (score 6):

Alt. hint:  let $\,x-1 = y \gt 0\,$, then:

$$
2x^3+2x^2-10x+6 = 2(y+1)^3+2(y+1)^2-10(y+1)+6=2 y^3 + 8y^2 \gt 0
$$

Comment: (+1) I wrote an answer using $2x^3+2x^2-10x+6=2(x-1)^3+8(x-1)^2$, but didn't post it since I then saw that it was the same as your answer.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks. The most direct way is of course to notice that $\,x=1\,$ is a root and factor it out, but that was already hinted in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2917559/291201), and spelled out in a [comment under it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917546/show-that-2x32x2-10x6-is-positive-if-x1/2917560?noredirect=1#comment6026919_2917559). The above is my "*alt.*" fallback for when one doesn't "see" the most direct way.

Answer (score 3):

$f'(x)=6x^2+4x-10 >0$ for

$x>1$, implies

$f$ stricly increasing for $x >1$.

Since $f(1)=0$, we have $f(x) >0$ for $x>1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(x)=2x^3+2x^2-10x+6$$ then $$f'(x)=6x²+4x-10$$ $$=(6x+10)(x-1)$$Now $f(x)$ is strictly increasing if $f'(x)>0$ or when $x$ belongs to $(-\infty , -\dfrac{10}{6}) \cup (1,\infty)$.

At $x=1$, $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in the interval $(1,\infty)$ so for values of $x$ greater than $1$, $f(x)$ will be greater than $0$ i.e. positive.

Comment: thanks, that works

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see, given function has a root at x=1. For x>1, function is increasing.
If you take derivative of function, it becomes f'(x)=6$x^2$+4x-10, which is positive for x>1.
 Therefore, function f(x) is increasing, (and positive since f(1)=0) for x>1.

Comment: Therefore $f(x)=2(x-1)^2(x+3)$.